# Issue in Excel: Copy a cell with formula - pastes value of the copied cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, copy-paste

I have the following copy and paste issue since yesterday. Probably it started when I was trying to edit a locked Excel-doc which i found on a shared server (that is - it was not created with my installed Excel). Similar but different from the thread [Excel copy-paste is only copying as values, but I want it to copy formulas](https://superuser.com/questions/412687/excel-copy-paste-is-only-copying-as-values-but-i-want-it-to-copy-formulas) (which was related to Skype, which I don't have on this machine).

**Steps to produce issue:**

```
1. Suppose A1 is " = 1 + 1 ".
The sheet shows 2 in cell A1, as it should.

2. Click on cell A1 and press Ctrl+C in order to copy the cell.

3. Click on cell A2 and press Ctrl+V in order to paste what is copied.

4. ---> The formula of A2 is 2 and not " = 1 + 1 ".
```

**What I have tried - without success:**

```
1. Change "Calculation options" in the excel folder "Formulas" from "Automatic" to "Manual" and back again..
2. Restart Excel - starting a new doc.
3. Restart Excel - opening an old doc.
4. Paste special giving the paste alternatives Text or Unicode.
5. Google searches - it seems to be a common issue in particular it occurs for [Skype users][2] who have a special plug-in.
```

2-3 above made it work for a while, but not for long (could it be a service ???)!

**Edit** Also, 4 is worthless because if I display the clipboard in order to show what is copied into the memory, then **nothing but the value of the cell is displayed in the clipboard!**

**My environment:**

```
  1. I remote virtual machine which use Win7 and Office 2007.
  2. I do not have Skype on the virtual machine (but I do have it on the local remoting computer)
```

**Do you have any idea?**

Comment: Just to clarify, you say the question you link to is similar, did you try the solution to it or do you not have the Skype add-in.

Comment: @Tog Hi, yes - in the end of the post I described the environment. There is no Skype involved here.

Comment: @Tog Added that explanation to the link. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have excel in front of me, but isn't there a 'Paste Special / Formulas' ?

Comment: @mcalex Yeah it is. Since he already mentioned this `Paste special giving the paste alternatives Text or Unicode` I guess he is aware of that option. But I don't know for sure. So lets ask him :)

Comment: @mcalex Yes, I tried that - in fact (I will **bold** that), I updated the post in order to mention that the clipboard does not have the formula - just the value! :(

Comment: Have you tried running Excel in Safe mode?

Comment: Could it be that any other program hooks into your clipboard, e.g. to exchange it between your virtual machine and your host? Try to disable it for a test...

Comment: @pnuts Yes that is right, the clipboard shows "2" - and no, as mentioned there is no Skype on the virtual machine.

Comment: @James That sounds like a good idea! I will try that tomorrow! :)

Comment: I presume you can (1) click on cell A1, (2) click in the formula bar, or press (F2) to edit in the cell, (3) select the entire contents of the cell, either with the mouse or by typing Ctrl+Home followed by Ctrl+Shift+End, (4) press Ctrl+C to copy the cell, (5) click on cell A2, (6) edit the cell (as in 2), (7) select the contents of the cell (as in 3), and (8) press Ctrl+V to paste.  I realize it’s not a viable, long-term solution, but it’s a workaround –– and, if this doesn’t work, your problem may be worse than you realize.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues with background processes like synergy and other tools that mangle with clipboard contents. **Alt-tab twice** does the trick here, back to normal clipboard behaivior.

And **libre office** calc seems to more robust with that problem.

Comment: You've saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem in Excel 2007. The solution I found was:

Click the Excel icon in the top left

Click on Excel options

In formulas (left hand side) make sure that the "Automatic" option is ticked in the Calculation options section.

Good luck!